# Suddenly can't run TestNG tests from ant ([testng] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException)

Tags: ant, testng

I am using ant and TestNG 6.1.1, and I had my tests working just fine yesterday.  Today when I try to run the tests I get a NoClassDefFoundError involving com/beust/jcommander/ParamException.  Here is the output:

```
[copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/djohnson/src/webapp/components/build/tmp
[testng] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
[testng] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
[testng]    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[testng]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[testng]    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[testng]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[testng]    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[testng]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[testng] The tests failed.
```

Here is the .xml file I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Single Method Suite">
  <test name="Single Method Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="DhcpTest">
        <methods>
          <exclude name=".*" />
          <include name="setGetEnabledTest" />
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I've also specified the complete path for the class with no luck.  I've checked the classpath and everything seems fine, does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Okay, so I have added jcommander-1.17.jar to the classpath, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Now that I have posted this for all the world to see, I discovered that jcommander wasn't actually in the classpath.  I was sure I saw it there, but sure enough it was missing.

Now it can't find the test, not sure why, because I've triple checked the classpath, and it's definitely there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using ant, JCommander should be inside testng.jar, so I'm thinking your testng.jar file might be corrupt.

Comment: Cedric, you are correct, I downloaded a copy of the testng.jar from the website and it worked just fine with out having a jcommander jar.  We are using ivy so apparently it has a corrupt file in the cache.  I'll have to look into getting that taken care of.

Thanks for helping me out, yet again.

Comment: Glad to hear it. FYI, `rm -rf ~/.ivy2/org.testng` should take care of the problem.

Comment: Cedric, it turns out that the file I'm using is the same file that is in the Maven 2 repository, so removing it from my ivy cache doesn't help.  Is there a problem with the file in the cache, or is there something else going on here?

Comment: I also faced this problem. According to Cedric Beust guidance I replaced old testng.jar with new one. And it's working well.

Answer (score 4):

If your using Maven try adding this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
  <version>1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

jcommander.jar (e.g. jcommander-1.29.jar) should be present on fileset directory which is mentioned at build.xml

You can download it from: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander/1.27

OR,

JCommander should be inside testng.jar during using ant. Your testng.jar file might be corrupted, so please replace old testng.jar by new one.

Answer (score 0):

May be testng.jar is not in classpath.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I checked the class path.  Please see Cedric's response above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with a non-Maven project.  I retrieved the testng jar from Maven Central, but it didn't contain all of TestNG's dependencies.  Downloading the jar directly from the TestNG site resolved the issue, as it contains the dependencies.

I should have paid more attention to the directions on [TestNG's download page](http://testng.org/doc/download.html)...

> The latest version of TestNG can be downloaded from **Maven Central** or **here for ant users**.

Answer (score 0):

My ant start working when I have downloaded jcommandar jar from
Maven repository and added it in my jar file

But This problem
Starts coming with testng 6.8.5 version

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that certain versions of the testNG jar do not have the jcommander jar code inside of them. As a result, you have to add the classpath to the Jcommander jar separately.

Adding the Jcommander jar to your classpath when you run it will fix the problem, hopefully