# Unable to run testng from command line

Tags: testng

I am able to run testng perfectly fine from within Eclipse. However, I want to run it using command line (Win 8) as explained on different forums. Here are different things I am trying with the errors -

```
1.
java -cp "D:\testng\testng-6.8.7.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/
ParameterException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterExcep
tion
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
2. java -cp "D:\testng\testng-6.8.7.jar:{$PATH_TILL_HERE}\target\test-classes\org\test\automation\links\LinksTest.cl
ass" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100821/suddenly-cant-run-testng-tests-from-ant-testng-caused-by-java-lang-classnot

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using surefire plugin to run TestNG tests using "mvn package" command and resolving all the dependency on external jars.

Comment: can u please tell the steps how to do that

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using a jar that does not contain dependencies like JCommander (probably the one created to use with Maven). Try using the jar from this [zip](http://testng.org/testng-6.8.zip).

Comment: worked fine for me (using testng 6.8) - where can i find tesng 6.9 (which we are using for our tests?

Answer (score 2):

In your command line command you try to run testng.jar, unfortunately testng.jar uses JCommander and it is a dependency. It must also have the location of that jar as well to execute.

java -cp "D:\testng\testng-6.8.7.jar":"this should be replaced with the path to your Jcommander jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
//hopefully this works

Someone should send a note to testng to put the jcommander code into their jar.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error suggests, you need to include [JCommander](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander/) in your classpath.  You can follow the above link to the most recent version and click the "Artifact" link to download the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

adding JCommander to the classpath solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `jcommander.jar` in `D:\testng` and run this command:

```
java -cp "D:\testng\*" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```