# how to run maven project testng.xml from the command prompt

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

I am using linux mechine(ubuntu 14). my project is maven project with testng frame work. here i am trying to run the testng.xml from the command prompt so that i can configure in jenkins.

```
project location : /home/subhash/workspace/myproject
class path is  : /home/subhash/workspace/myproject/bin
testng jar locattion is: /home/subhash/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.9.4/testng-6.9.4.jar"

suite location is : /home/subhash/workspace/suites/src/test/resources/testng.xml

hence i executed the following command from command prompt from the location.
/home/subhash/workspace/myproject/bin$ 

$ java -cp ".:../lib/*:/home/subhash/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.9.4/testng-6.9.4.jar" org.testng.TestNG /home/subhash/workspace/suites/src/test/resources/testng.xml
```

i got the following Exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException`

hence i have added the dependency in pom.xml as follows.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.beust</groupId>
<artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
<version>1.48</version>
```

build it. it was successful.
again i have run the above mentioned command to run the testng.xml but still same exception is displayed.

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Subhash.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Suddenly can't run TestNG tests from ant ([testng] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100821/suddenly-cant-run-testng-tests-from-ant-testng-caused-by-java-lang-classnot)

It seems to be the same problem

Hope helps!

**UPDATE**

Try to add to the cp java argument the 'beust' jar path in m2.

Comment: Hi Francis, Thank you for ur post. i have gone through that, as suggested in the post. i have replaced my testng.jar file with latest and tried to run the testng.xml file again still Exception is displaed, still following exception is displayed. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

Comment: Hi Subash, did you try to add to the -cp java argument the 'beust' jar path? Do it in the same way you have added the testng jar path

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier running the tests using mvn test instead of the testng jar.
Setup the [mvn surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) plugin in pom and run using mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/yourxml.xml

Comment: i tried adding this plugin and run the maven test. exception is displayed.Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on test-suite: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file /home/subhash/workspace/test-suite/test_suite_main.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:115)

Comment: It says suite file is not valid.  Is this path accessible from where your maven is running?

Comment: Just put the file in your project and use src/test/resources/testng.xml..no need to give absolute path