# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm trying to run a very simple test using TestNG, but I'm getting this error message. I tried reading the previous answers, but it is not working to me. I would be happy if someone could help me out, since I'm just a beginner in TestNG. This is the error message :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException

Comment: Can you post the code that's giving you the exception?

Comment: Code is needed. You probably don't put correct annotations. Pleas provide your code and information how you run tests.

Answer (score 2):

TestNG has some mandatory dependencies. JCommander is one of them.

So just add it in your classpath.

But, you should really use a modern build tool like Maven or Gradle which are helping you to forget such kind of issues.

Have a look on [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/download.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

### In configuration level,

### For maven users:

If your using Maven try adding this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
  <version>1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

### For ant users:

If you're using ant, JCommander should be inside `testng.jar`, so I'm thinking your testng.jar file might be corrupt.

### Resource Link:

1. [Suddenly can't run TestNG tests from ant ([testng] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100821/suddenly-cant-run-testng-tests-from-ant-testng-caused-by-java-lang-classnot)

### [For eclipse luna users:](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/140)

you can simply add jcommander.jar to your project classpath, then run test again