# Java Virtual Machine Launcher Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have read plenty of threads on **Stackoverflow** & tried out lots of solutions on google ,regarding this issue.
and for each time I also have cleaned %appdata% of the old content for java and eclipse + cleaned regedit.

also tested all several solutions but nothing have been working for me.

I am currently testing to make this work with:

- Window 10 64 bit
- eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64
- jre-7u65-windows-x64

this is my code for my project:

```js
package tets;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class Testcase {
 String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Server\\geckodriver.exe";
 public WebDriver driver;
 
 @Test
 public void LaunchBrowser(){
  System.out.println("Launching Mozilla Firefox Browser");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath+"geckodriver.exe");
  driver =new FirefoxDriver(); 
 }
 
 @Test
 public void openApplication(){
  driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.se");
 }
 
}
```

**This is how my Library looks like:**

[image]

**This is my Environment Variables:**
[image]

Notice I also tested to put a Variable for my User also but no result:
**This is how my **Eclipse.ini** file looks like:**

```html
-startup
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

This is the Error when I press on run button:

[image]

[image]

Let me know if you need even more information.

I have also tested to download & install Java devkit from:

I also have tested to download the latest versions of eclipse and Java both x86 + 64bit associated to each other.

Could someone help me?

thank you in advance

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: Your build path is separate from your launch path. Open *Run>Run Configurations...* and switch to the *ClassPath* tab. Ensure that the jar that contains the missing class is included on the classpath of the launcher.

Comment: I have added the external jar files to the ClassPath see link:
still same result --> https://i.imgur.com/Cz25fq9.png

Comment: Does the jar jcommander-1.15-sources contain *.class files, in the expected path, in addition to source files?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100821/suddenly-cant-run-testng-tests-from-ant-testng-caused-by-java-lang-classnot) and the answers? It looks worth investigating. One suggestion is to redownload the testng.jar and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at you code, I see that you have `geckodriver.exe` as part of driverPath. When you are setting the property, you are adding an extra `geckodriver.exe`.

I would recommend removing "geckodriver.exe" from your driverPath and try.

```
driverPath = C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Server;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath+"geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: I tested this morning didn't work either so frustating put 2 days to just make this work could you please help me by remote?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved with the following steps:

1. I closed eclipse
2. I deleted the `.metadata` folder from my workspace
3. I opened eclipse, tried again and it worked

Comment: didn't work just made my projects disappear from the project list

Comment: In this folder are all configuration of projects, sometimes for some reason it crashes and projects do not work properly, you can import again

Comment: yeah I know but I get the same result no matter which version of eclipse I am using I also delete this folder of each instance i install too but thanks

Comment: Sorry man, this workaround deleted the message: `a java exception has occurred`